# Play Framework jpa and postgresql

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm new with Play.
I use the 2.0 Version
I try to connect my projet to a postgresql databse and use jpa to retreived data.
I can connect to the database but i fail to lauch request with jpa.

When i try in my User model in methode authenticate

```
Query query = JPA.em().createQuery("myQuery")
```

I have this message '

```
[RuntimeExeption: No EntityManager bound to this thread. Try to annotate your action method with @play.db.jpa.Transactional]
```

Sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: Could you please show the structure of your model ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to anotate the method of the controller that calls User.autenticate() with @Transactional (package play.db.jpa).